# Insert multi rows INTO MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a such select:

```
$sql = "SELECT milestone_id, project_id, sum(estimated_hours) as value_sum
FROM project_has_tasks GROUP BY milestone_id";
```

Getting a multiple results.
Is this possible to create a query to INSERT these results to multiple rows in DB?

Comment: `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { //doInsert }`

Comment: `VALUES ('?', '?', '?'` that's also failing you.

Comment: Ok so how the query should looks like in all? VALUES are not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to myself :) Is so simple as ....

```
   <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "db";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO `burndown_snap` (`project_id`,`milestone_id`,`estimated_sum`)
SELECT `project_id`, `milestone_id`, sum(estimated_hours) as value_sum FROM project_has_tasks WHERE status !='done' GROUP BY milestone_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$conn->close();
?>
```